# Why absolutely positioned parent element width is zero?

Tags: css

> Absolute positioning allows you to literally place any page element exactly where you want it. You use the positioning attributes top, left bottom and right to set the location. These values will be relative to the next parent element with **relative (or absolute) positioning**. If there is no such parent, it will default all the way back up to the  element itself meaning it will be placed relatively to the page itself.

Below is the code, where absolute positioned child(`p`) will be relative to the next parent element(`div`) with **absolute positioning**, but the `div` block width is **zero**.

```
<div  style= "position:absolute;">
    <p style = "position:absolute; top:4px; left:5px;">
        text text
    </p>
    <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/>
    <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> 
</div>
```

Below is the code, where absolute positioned child(`p`) will be relative to the next parent element(`div`) with **relative positioning**, with the `div` block width as **non-zero**.

```
<div style= "position:relative;">
    <p style = "position:absolute; top: 1px; left: 5px;">
        text text
    </p>
    <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/>
    <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> 
</div>
```

In first case, Why absolutely positioned parent element(`div`) width is zero?

Comment: Absolutely positioned elements _don't_ make their own width, they need to be defined. A static div is automatically 100% wide, but as soon as you position it absolute it loses this width in favor of a predefined width. Static (and relative) elements will be pushed by their contents, but absolute ones wont.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely positioned elements *don't* decide their own width, they need to be *defined*. A static div is automatically `100%` wide, but as soon as you position it `absolute` it loses this width in favor of a predefined width, or the default `0`. Static (and relative) elements will be *pushed* by their contents, but absolute ones *won't*.

Comment: Absolute positioned elements collapse to the width of their content up to a maximum of the position context ancestor's width.

Comment: Can I say, absolutely positioned elements don't decide their own width or height, relative(or static) positioned elements don't decide their own height(only) ?

Comment: @overexchange This is true in theory, but in practise browsers do give them some basic widths. Anyhow, I'd love to link to the specs but I can't really find it at first glance. This answer is more experience than cold, hard, proven fact - but it's a good way of thinking about it.

Answer (score 3):

As per the specs here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#abs-pos:

> In the absolute positioning model... is removed from the normal flow
>   entirely... absolutely positioned box establishes a new containing
>   block for normal flow children and absolutely (but not fixed or page)
>   positioned descendants..

In the example you provided, the `div` is absolutely positioned and hence is removed from the normal flow. Not only that, the descendant `p` is also absolutely positioned and hence is also removed from the flow, but its containing block is established by the `div`.

Now, from the specs here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#abs-non-replaced-width (*emphasis mine*):

> If all three of `left`, `width`, and `right` are `auto`: First set any `auto`
>   values for `margin-left` and `margin-right` to `0`. Then, if the `direction`
>   property of the element establishing the static-position containing
>   block is ltr set left to the static position and ***apply rule number
>   three*** below; otherwise, set right to the static-position and apply
>   rule number one below.

So, in your example the `left`, `right` and `width` are absent from properties the rule number three applies (*ignore direction property as of now, rules one and three are same regarding the width*).

The rule 3 states (*emphasis mine*):

> If `width` and `right` are `auto` and `left` is not `auto`, then the `width` is
>   ***shrink-to-fit***. Then solve for `right`.

With the child `p` out of the flow, what remains there to derive the width of the `div` to make it shrink-to-fit? The only text content it has, is `breaks`.

Effectively, this shrinks the `div` to `0`.

---

For the `p` inside that `div`, the same rules apply. It also shrinks-to-fit, but its containing block is established by its ancestor `div` (*see first ref above*). So it will shrink within the bounds of the container `div` trying to accommodate as much content as possible.

Add this style to the `p` - `word-break: break-all` and you will see that the `p` will then shrink to a width to accommodate one character.